# Weyl's theorem over non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Weyl's theorem states that every finite-dimensional representation of a semisimple Lie algebra is completely reducible, meaning it is a direct sum of irreducible submodules. In Humphreys' book *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* (section 6.3), this is proved in the case that the base field is algebraically closed of characteristic 0. Similarly, in Hall's book *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations* (section 10.3), the base field is assumed to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Does Weyl's theorem hold over fields that are not algebraically closed? In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1253975/467879) from 6 years ago, Dietrich Burde says "one can apply an argument, that the statement is already true for $K$ if it was true for the algebraic closure of $K$." Is there such an argument, and if so, what is it? I know that in general, an irreducible representation may become reducible over a field extension, so it's not clear to me why complete reducibility over $\overline{K}$ would imply complete reducibility over $K$.

Comment: That an irrep can become reducible over a field extension has little to do with the question: First, as long as it stays a sum of irreducibles, complete reducibility would be preserved; secondly and more importantly, we want to conclude *in the other direction* i.e. from complete reducibility over the field extension to over the small field. Or equivalently, what's to show is that something *not* completely reducible over the ground field will also be *not* completely reducible over an extension.

Comment: It is not necessary to assume that $K$ is algebraically closed, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_theorem_on_complete_reducibility) with proofs.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks for your response. I have been trying to show something like the following: if $V$ is a representation of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over $K$, and $V' \subseteq V$ is a subrepresentation which has no complement in $V$, then for a field extension $L \supseteq K$ the representation $V' \otimes_K L$ cannot have a complement in $V \otimes_K L$. Is this what you had in mind, or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @DietrichBurde The Wikipedia article seems to have some gaps with respect to this assumption. The article cites Hall's book in the first paragraph, but Hall assumes the field is algebraically closed. At least some of the proofs seem to assume algebraic closure, too: for example "Algebraic proof 2" appears to use the version of Schur's lemma over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @Tamar: That was my vague idea, but to be honest I have not actually put thought into it yet.

Comment: The Jacobson book seems to cover all fields of characteristic zero. He attributes the given proof to Whitehead.

Comment: @Tamar Yes, it is sometimes convenient to prove  Weyl's Theorem first for algebraically closed fields. But there is also a proof using Whitehead's Lemma, which is true for fields of characteristic zero. See Theorem $8$ on page $79$ in Jacobson's book *Lie Algebras*.

Comment: Thank you! Jacobson's book is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer for $K = \mathbb R$ can be found [here](https://faubox.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/dl/fiMYUbDntWM7oPPUUy3T55Fu/?inline#page43) in Proposition 5.24. As Torsten Schoeneberg pointed out in the comments this method provides a proof in the general case aswell.

Comment: Not just partial, it seems to me that the proof idea for the direction (ii) $\implies$ (i) (the one relevant for OP) generalizes easily from the extension $\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R$ to a general $K^{alg} \vert K$, and I guess that is what Dietrich Burde had in mind in OP's reference.

Comment: How exactly? Does there always exist a map like $\text{Re}\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: For any field extension $L\vert K$ we can extend the element $1 \in K$ to a $K$-basis $B$ of $L$ (if the dimension is countable, say $B=\{e_1=1, e_2, e_3, ...\}$). Then the projection map $pr_B: L \rightarrow K$ which is the identity on $K$ but sends each other basis element to $0$ is $K$-linear and can play the role of the real part in that proof, in particular every element of $W_L$ can be written uniquely as $\sum e_i \otimes w_i$ with $w_i \in W$, and we can define $q_W$ as sending such a sum to $w_1 \in W$.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two references for this version of Weyl's theorem (characteristic 0 but not algebraically closed):

- Jacobson's *Lie Algebras* does not assume the base field is algebraically closed. Weyl's theorem is Theorem 8 in Chapter III.7, and the proof is via Whitehead's lemma.
- It is also Theorem 7.8.11 in Weibel's *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*. The proof uses cohomology.